# What is the alocation size for python containers

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

What is/how can I find the default memory allocation size for the python containers.  That is, how many items can be appended, inserted before the underlying implementation must allocate more memory.

```
dict(), list(), tuple(), set(), frozenset()
```

and can it be changed.

Comment: Those are implementation details and you cannot change them.

Comment: Thanks.   I just found  `sys.getsizeof()`.  This lets me detect when the size changes, which is basically what I need.